# Can I install composite decking directly on top of concrete?

Tags: deck, vinyl, composite

Is it ok to add a flat deck over this concrete pad( the pad is about 5 inches tall, and slightly slopes away from the house.

How would I go about adding decking over it. I'm pretty handy but just wants some tips.

[image]

Also would the same application apply for these stairs?
[image: stairs]

Comment: Do you really want to install a new material right over top of a crumbling concrete pad?  That sounds like a recipe for premature failure to me.  I'd remove the concrete first.

Comment: Power nailing the composite decking to the concrete would likely do in the _very expensive_ composite decking.

Answer (score 4):

You can install composite decking on top of concrete but not directly. You would need to build a frame on top of the concrete similar to a normal deck. The framing could be smaller than normal, 2" x 2" and it would be secured directly to the concrete. The distancing of the "joists" would be the same as what the decking calls for. The reason for the frame is that the composite decking still need to be aired out. Your stairs would require the same type of framing. Stairs can be tricky so you'd want to check with local coded.

The problem you have with this procedure is that your concrete is all busted up and securing your frame to it correctly will be all but impossible unless you repaired it, which would be crazy.

You could build an entirely new deck over the concrete with a larger frame not supported by the concrete. Your best choice would be to remove the concrete and start fresh.

Comment: Might be able to do with furring strips but it looks pretty far gone.

Comment: I agree, but there's no reason it has to be secured to the concrete. Composite decking is heavy. It ain't going nowhere.

Answer (score 0):

Once the concrete is repaired or replaced, you install the framing using "sleepers" or treated 2x4s lying on their wider sides. They should be anchored into the concrete. Then you lay the composite decking perpendicular to the sleepers and parallel to the house wall and screw it into the sleepers. Be sure to leave space between boards as they will expand in the sun. I did this project and it was the best improvement to my home!